# elastic search sum aggregate only on matched document id

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am new to elasticsearch I have two documents with unique id's in my document it is exceptionId when the exceptionId is 1 then it correctly returns the sum aggregation for document 1 but if i want the sum aggregation of both the documents individually if my input is exceptionId 1 and 2 then elasticsearch will do the summation of both the documents and returning the result in my case for the matched input the corresponding document sum aggregation should return and when the input are multiple then aggregation should be multiple.

This is the mapping.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "recommendations": {
            "properties": {
                "events": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "recommendationData": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "recommendations": {
                                    "type": "nested",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "recommendationType": {
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the document with exceptionId as "1"

```
{
    "clusterId": "1",
    "rank": 1,
    "events": [
        {
            "eventId": "1",
            "eventType": "Delayed",
            "metaInfo": {
                "batch_id": "batch_1"
            },
            "recommendationData": [
                {
                    "exceptionId": "1",
                    "item": "KitKat",
                    "location": "DC1",
                    "dueDate": "2019-01-10T05:30:00.000+0530",
                    "quantity": 100,
                    "metaInfo": {
                        "batch_id": "batch_1",
                        "dummy_id": "dummy_1"
                    },
                    "rank": 1,
                    "recommendations": [
                        {
                            "rank": 1,
                            "recommendationType": "Out Of Stock",
                            "customerName": "Walmart",
                            "stockTransfer": {
                                "primaryRecommendation": true,
                                "priority": 1,
                                "sourceLocation": "DC1",
                                "transferQuantity": 100,
                                "metaInfo": 40,
                                "shipDate": "01/01/2020",
                                "arrivalDate": "10/01/2020",
                                "transportMode": "Air",
                                "transferCost": 1000,
                                "maxQtyAvailableForTransfer": 40,
                                "totalQtyAtSource": 1,
                                "revenueRecovered": 12000
                            },
                            "expedite": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the document with exceptionId as "2"

```
{
    "clusterId": "2",
    "rank": 2,
    "events": [
        {
            "eventId": "2",
            "eventType": "Delayed",
            "metaInfo": {
                "batch_id": "batch_1"
            },
            "recommendationData": [
                {
                    "exceptionId": "2",
                    "item": "KitKat",
                    "location": "DC1",
                    "dueDate": "2019-01-10T05:30:00.000+0530",
                    "quantity": 100,
                    "metaInfo": {
                        "batch_id": "batch_1",
                        "dummy_id": "dummy_1"
                    },
                    "rank": 1,
                    "recommendations": [
                        {
                            "rank": 1,
                            "recommendationType": "Out Of Stock",
                            "customerName": "Walmart",
                            "stockTransfer": {
                                "primaryRecommendation": true,
                                "priority": 1,
                                "sourceLocation": "DC1",
                                "transferQuantity": 100,
                                "metaInfo": 40,
                                "shipDate": "01/01/2020",
                                "arrivalDate": "10/01/2020",
                                "transportMode": "Air",
                                "transferCost": 1000,
                                "maxQtyAvailableForTransfer": 40,
                                "totalQtyAtSource": 1,
                                "revenueRecovered": 12000
                            },
                            "expedite": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the query i have tried

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "recommendations": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "events.recommendationData"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "exceptionId": {
                    "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "events.recommendationData.exceptionId": [
                                "1", "2"
                            ],
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "by_item": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "events.recommendationData.item.keyword",
                                "size": 10,
                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                "order": [
                                    {
                                        "_count": "desc"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_key": "asc"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "aggregations": {
                                "by_destination": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "events.recommendationData.location.keyword",
                                        "size": 10,
                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                        "order": [
                                            {
                                                "_count": "desc"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_key": "asc"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "aggregations": {
                                        "recommendations": {
                                            "nested": {
                                                "path": "events.recommendationData.recommendations"
                                            },
                                            "aggregations": {
                                                "by_trans": {
                                                    "terms": {
                                                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.transportMode.keyword",
                                                        "size": 10,
                                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                        "order": [
                                                            {
                                                                "_count": "desc"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "_key": "asc"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "aggregations": {
                                                        "by_sourcelocation": {
                                                            "terms": {
                                                                "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.sourceLocation.keyword",
                                                                "size": 10,
                                                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                                "order": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "_count": "desc"
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "_key": "asc"
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            "aggregations": {
                                                                "by_shipdate": {
                                                                    "terms": {
                                                                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.shipDate.keyword",
                                                                        "size": 10,
                                                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                                        "order": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "_count": "desc"
                                                                            },
                                                                            {
                                                                                "_key": "asc"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    },
                                                                    "aggregations": {
                                                                        "by_arrival": {
                                                                            "terms": {
                                                                                "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.arrivalDate.keyword",
                                                                                "size": 10,
                                                                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                                                "order": [
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "_count": "desc"
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "_key": "asc"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                ]
                                                                            },
                                                                            "aggregations": {
                                                                                "quantity": {
                                                                                    "sum": {
                                                                                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.transferQuantity"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                },
                                                                                "transfercost": {
                                                                                    "sum": {
                                                                                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.transferCost"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                },
                                                                                "revenueRecovered": {
                                                                                    "sum": {
                                                                                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.revenueRecovered"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output here it is doing all summation from document 1 and document 2

```
       {
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "recommendations": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "exceptionId": {
                "doc_count": 2,
                "by_item": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "KitKat",
                            "doc_count": 2,
                            "by_destination": {
                                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "key": "DC1",
                                        "doc_count": 2,
                                        "recommendations": {
                                            "doc_count": 2,
                                            "by_trans": {
                                                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                "buckets": [
                                                    {
                                                        "key": "Air",
                                                        "doc_count": 2,
                                                        "by_sourcelocation": {
                                                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                            "buckets": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "key": "DC1",
                                                                    "doc_count": 2,
                                                                    "by_shipdate": {
                                                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                                        "buckets": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "key": "01/01/2020",
                                                                                "doc_count": 2,
                                                                                "by_arrival": {
                                                                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                                                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                                                    "buckets": [
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            "key": "10/01/2020",
                                                                                            "doc_count": 2,
                                                                                            "quantity": {
                                                                                                "value": 200.0
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            "transfercost": {
                                                                                                "value": 2000.0
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            "revenueRecovered": {
                                                                                                "value": 24000.0
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    ]
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your requirement, you need a terms aggregation on "exceptionId"
Let me know if this works for you
Query:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "recommendations": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "events.recommendationData"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "exceptionId": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "events.recommendationData.exceptionId": [
                "1",
                "2"
              ],
              "boost": 1
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "exceptionId": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "events.recommendationData.exceptionId.keyword",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "by_item": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "events.recommendationData.item.keyword",
                    "size": 10,
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                    "order": [
                      {
                        "_count": "desc"
                      },
                      {
                        "_key": "asc"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "aggregations": {
                    "by_destination": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "events.recommendationData.location.keyword",
                        "size": 10,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [
                          {
                            "_count": "desc"
                          },
                          {
                            "_key": "asc"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "aggregations": {
                        "recommendations": {
                          "nested": {
                            "path": "events.recommendationData.recommendations"
                          },
                          "aggregations": {
                            "by_trans": {
                              "terms": {
                                "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.transportMode.keyword",
                                "size": 10,
                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                "order": [
                                  {
                                    "_count": "desc"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "_key": "asc"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              "aggregations": {
                                "by_sourcelocation": {
                                  "terms": {
                                    "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.sourceLocation.keyword",
                                    "size": 10,
                                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                    "order": [
                                      {
                                        "_count": "desc"
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "_key": "asc"
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  "aggregations": {
                                    "by_shipdate": {
                                      "terms": {
                                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.shipDate.keyword",
                                        "size": 10,
                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                        "order": [
                                          {
                                            "_count": "desc"
                                          },
                                          {
                                            "_key": "asc"
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      },
                                      "aggregations": {
                                        "by_arrival": {
                                          "terms": {
                                            "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.arrivalDate.keyword",
                                            "size": 10,
                                            "min_doc_count": 1,
                                            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                            "order": [
                                              {
                                                "_count": "desc"
                                              },
                                              {
                                                "_key": "asc"
                                              }
                                            ]
                                          },
                                          "aggregations": {
                                            "quantity": {
                                              "sum": {
                                                "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.transferQuantity"
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "transfercost": {
                                              "sum": {
                                                "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.transferCost"
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "revenueRecovered": {
                                              "sum": {
                                                "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.stockTransfer.revenueRecovered"
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "recommendations" : {
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "exceptionId" : {
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "exceptionId" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "1",
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "by_item" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : "KitKat",
                    "doc_count" : 1,
                    "by_destination" : {
                      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                      "buckets" : [
                        {
                          "key" : "DC1",
                          "doc_count" : 1,
                          "recommendations" : {
                            "doc_count" : 1,
                            "by_trans" : {
                              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                              "buckets" : [
                                {
                                  "key" : "Air",
                                  "doc_count" : 1,
                                  "by_sourcelocation" : {
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                                    "buckets" : [
                                      {
                                        "key" : "DC1",
                                        "doc_count" : 1,
                                        "by_shipdate" : {
                                          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                                          "buckets" : [
                                            {
                                              "key" : "01/01/2020",
                                              "doc_count" : 1,
                                              "by_arrival" : {
                                                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                                                "buckets" : [
                                                  {
                                                    "key" : "10/01/2020",
                                                    "doc_count" : 1,
                                                    "quantity" : {
                                                      "value" : 100.0
                                                    },
                                                    "transfercost" : {
                                                      "value" : 1000.0
                                                    },
                                                    "revenueRecovered" : {
                                                      "value" : 12000.0
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                ]
                                              }
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes jaspreet! indeed i have needed this one exactly...Thanks